# Javascript push object into array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

im using node mirc to retrieve data from mysql

[image]

then i want convert data to array, using code below :

```
function getQuestion (arr{
    var obj = {};

    connection.connect();
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM quiz", function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rows[i];
            obj = {"id":row.id, "question":row.question, "answers":row.answers.split(", ")};
            f100.push(obj);
        };
    });
    connection.end();
}
f100 = [];
getQuestion();
console.log(f100);
```

but, its only print `[]`

Comment: check if any rows are being retrieved by putting a console.log() statement after the for each statement, to pinpoint where exactly is the problem.

Comment: Because of JS Asynchronous behavior!!

Comment: @YahyaUddin the data retrieved without problem, im already test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to `.query()'s` async behavior its taking some time to execute, but you're executing the log just after calling the function. You need to put the log withing callback of `.query()` function.

```
function getQuestion (arr{
    var obj = {};

    connection.connect();
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM quiz", function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rows[i];
            obj = {"id":row.id, "question":row.question, "answers":row.answers.split(", ")};
            f100.push(obj);
        };

        // do log here
        console.log(f100);
    });
    connection.end();
}
f100 = [];
getQuestion();
```

Answer (score 1):

`connection.query` is asynchronous, so i'd recommend consoling out `f100` inside the `connection.query` callback. If you want to do something with `f100` after it's finished populating, you'd need to pass it into another function from inside the connection query callback. Example:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM quiz", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        obj = {"id":row.id, "question":row.question, "answers":row.answers.split(", ")};
        f100.push(obj);
    };

    console.log(f100); // should console out correctly here
    handleArray(f100); // passes in f100 to a new function
});
```